# javascript unshift arguments returns unexpected results

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
router.route = function (alias, pattern, action, constraints) {
   if (2 === arguments.length)
     Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, undefined)

   console.log(arguments)
}

router.route('/artist/:id', function () {})


{ '0': undefined,
  '1': '/artist/:id',
  '2': [Function],
  '3': undefined,
  '4': undefined,
  '5': undefined,
  '6': undefined,
  '7': undefined,
  '8': undefined,
  '9': undefined,
  '10': undefined,
  '11': undefined,
  '12': undefined,
  '13': undefined,
  '14': undefined,
  '15': undefined,
  '16': undefined,
  '17': undefined,
  '18': undefined,
  '19': undefined }
```

what i'm basically trying to do, is to make the "alias" argument optional
but i'm trying to find a way of doing so without doing this.

```
if (2 === arguments.length) {
  action = pattern
  pattern = alias
  alias = undefined
}
```

so the unshift() basically works i get the same result.
`alias = undefined`
`pattern = '/artist/:id'`
`action = function () {}`

but the problem is that out of nowhere i have 17 "undefined's" added to the end of the arguments array.

will this affect performance, and does anybody knows why that happened ?

### edit

i accidentally wrote Array.prototype.unshift(arguments, undefined) instead of Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, undefined) in my original question, very sorry.

Comment: I would look at what console.log (arguments) shows before the unshift.

Comment: This will happen any time you apply unshift to an arguments object. [].unshift(arguments, 'string') will cause the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If those undefined places are there because of a resource timing out then yes, the performance will be affected.  If it is just an empty array index then No it will not affect performance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, don't you just want to remove the first element of the array?

If so you can just do:

```
var args = Array.prototype.shift.call(arguments);
```

Comment: I think OP wants the opposite. The `alias` argument is optional, so if only 3 args are passed, it's assumed that `alias` was left off, so the values that were passed need to be moved over to their proper parameters, leaving `alias` undefined.